# ExpressionEngine query module and ordering SQL UNION

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

I'm receiving a MySQL Error on this code in ExpressionEngine 1.6.4 (very old version)

```
{exp:query  limit="10" paginate="bottom"
    sql="SELECT 'gallery' AS `content_type`, `cat_id` AS `entry_id`, `recent_entry_date` AS `entry_date`
        FROM `exp_gallery_categories`
        WHERE `gallery_id` = 9 AND total_files > 0
        UNION
        SELECT 'video' AS `content_type`, `entry_id`, `entry_date`
        FROM `exp_weblog_titles`
        WHERE `weblog_id` = 6 ORDER BY `entry_date` DESC"

    }
<p>{content_type} - {entry_id} - {entry_date format="%d %F %Y"}</p>
{paginate}{pagination_links}{/paginate}
{/exp:query}
```

MySQL returns this:

```
MySQL ERROR: Error Number: 1054
Description: Unknown column 'entry_date' in 'order clause'
Query: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `exp_gallery_categories` WHERE `gallery_id` = 9 AND total_files > 0 UNION SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `exp_weblog_titles` WHERE `weblog_id` = 6 ORDER BY `entry_date` DESC
```

It seems like EE is modifying my query before MySQL and making it fail (On a SQL client this works smoothly).

Comment: FYI: There is now an EE specific Stack Exchange site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com. You can post future EE related questions there.

Comment: If I remove `{paginate}{pagination_links}{/paginate}` everything works but I get all the results and lose pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to patch **mod.query.php** to stop modifing the query

```
$query = $DB->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ({$sql}) AS query");
```

Here is the ultimate in-depth answer by Dom Stubbs: [ExpressionEngine 1 Query Module and Ordering SQL UNION](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1438/150)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your select queries work. Try below:

```
 sql="SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT gallery AS content_type, cat_id AS entry_id, 
          recent_entry_date AS entry_date
          FROM exp_gallery_categories
          WHERE gallery_id = 9 AND total_files > 0
          UNION
          SELECT video AS content_type, entry_id, entry_date
          FROM exp_weblog_titles
          WHERE weblog_id= 6 
         ) AS TEMP
       ORDER BY entry_date DESC"
```

EDIT: Count query:

```
         SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
              recent_entry_date AS entry_date
              FROM exp_gallery_categories 
              WHERE gallery_id = 9 AND total_files > 0 
              UNION 
              SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
              entry_date
              FROM exp_weblog_titles 
              WHERE weblog_id = 6 
           ) AS TEMP 
         ORDER BY entry_date DESC
```

Comment: Same error but changed result query:
Query: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `exp_gallery_categories` WHERE `gallery_id` = 9 AND total_files > 0 UNION SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `exp_weblog_titles` WHERE `weblog_id` = 6 ) AS TEMP ORDER BY `entry_date` DESC

Comment: @Angus Two questions: 1. Are your individual select queries running fine? 2. Try removing all the quotes in the query as don't look homogeneous single quotes and try(I updated the answer)?

Comment: @Angus In your count query, I see that you removed the `entry_date` from the select list hence it giving the right error. I posted the modified query. Please try.

Comment: The problem is there I think. The count query isn't mine but it is returned after the MySQL error as the query that has been (generated by EE and) actually executed. My query works fine even in EE sql manager but in a template it comes under some sort of tranformation.

Comment: @Angus Did you try individual select queries and final query without quotes?

Comment: `SELECT 'gallery' AS content_type, cat_id as entry_id,
          recent_entry_date
          FROM exp_gallery_categories
          WHERE gallery_id = 9 AND total_files > 0
    ORDER BY recent_entry_date`.
This works.
But this doesn't:
`SELECT 'gallery' AS content_type, cat_id as entry_id,
          recent_entry_date AS entry_date
          FROM exp_gallery_categories
          WHERE gallery_id = 9 AND total_files > 0
    ORDER BY entry_date`
Aliasing fields doesn't work so I cant't perform UNION on queries